# How to brute force JWT token for the sercret?

Tags: jwt, decode, brute-force, secret-key, cracking

I have a jwt token that I would like to try an brute force, to find the secret signature. How can I do this? I researched it a bit, and I ran across 'jwt-cracker' in node.js, but that didn't work.

Comment: Which signature algorithm this token is made of? HS256, RS256, etc.?

Comment: When you say it did not worked, what do you mean? Error code? Crash?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo Hi, it is HS256. And, it just kept going up in attempts. I left it for hours and it went up to 1 billion. I even tried a simple secret, still didn't work, it just kept incrementing in attempts.

Comment: If the secret has been correctly chosen, for instance from a random number generator or from a password that has been process by a correct key derivation function like PBKDF2, you need to wait a little more than one hour. Depending on the number of GPU procs you get, this can last from hundreds of years to billions.